# Access Collection PL/SQL

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Here is a pl/sql query which I am trying to understand:

```
TYPE REC_ASSMNTCOMP IS RECORD (RF_CUST_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_TIMESTAMP DATE, RF_BC_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_OP_COMPVALUE NUMBER);
TYPE TBL_ASSMNTCOMP_T IS TABLE OF REC_ASSMNTCOMP INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
TYPE TBL_ASSMNTCOMP IS TABLE OF TBL_ASSMNTCOMP_T INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

TYPE REC_ADJCOMP IS RECORD (RF_CUST_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_TIMESTAMP DATE, RF_BC_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_ADJ_COMPVALUE NUMBER);
TYPE TBL_ADJCOMP_T IS TABLE OF REC_ADJCOMP INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

TYPE REC_OPENCOMP IS RECORD (RF_BILLCYC_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_CUST_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_COMPTYPE NUMBER, RF_BC_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_COMPVALUE NUMBER);
TYPE TBL_OPENCOMP IS TABLE OF REC_OPENCOMP INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;

V_DOC_ID                NUMBER;
V_PROCESSING_DATE       DATE;

V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP        TBL_ASSMNTCOMP;
V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP_T      TBL_ASSMNTCOMP_T;

V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T         TBL_ADJCOMP_T;

V_TBL_OPENCOMP          TBL_OPENCOMP;


IF V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_TIMESTAMP < V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP(V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_CUST_ID_REF)(V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP(V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_CUST_ID_REF).FIRST).RF_TIMESTAMP
   THEN
```

The confusing part is below:

```
V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP(V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_CUST_ID_REF)(V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP(V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_CUST_ID_REF).FIRST).RF_TIMESTAMP
```

what the line above is doing ?

Comment: It is some kind of fiendishly complex hierarchical structure I think. What are the definitions of the TYPEs of these variables?

Comment: @TonyAndrews TYPE REC_ASSMNTCOMP IS RECORD (RF_CUST_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_TIMESTAMP DATE, RF_BC_ID_REF NUMBER, RF_OP_COMPVALUE NUMBER);

Answer (score 1):

It could be re-written broken down as this:

```
-- (Declare IDX NUMBER)
-- Get the RF_CUST_ID_REF from the I'th V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T record
IDX := V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_CUST_ID_REF;   

-- (Declare REC with same type as rows of V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP)
-- Get the V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP record indexed by that RF_CUST_ID_REF 
REC := V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP(IDX);

IF V_TBL_ADJCOMP_T(I).RF_TIMESTAMP < REC(REC.FIRST).RF_TIMESTAMP THEN...
```

That still doesn't mean much to me, but maybe it will to you? It appears that V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP is a table whose structure includes another table - i.e. that the REC I declared above is both a table and a row within V_TBL_ASSMNTCOMP ?

See [this PDF](http://tutorials.plsqlchannel.com/public/Presentations/CL10/CL10.pdf) for an explanation by Steven Feuerstein of the sort of "multi-level" collection I think you may be dealing with.

Comment: I reminded of "Beware of clever, clever kills".  @Zubair Make sure you learn from this and use comments and write for the person that will be maintaining the code behind you.  The original author thought he was being clever but in the long run his code is more expensive as now you are spending time figuring it out instead of making changes. When you have it figured out make sure to comment it thoroughly.

Comment: @TonyAndrews: Can you see the code again, I added more details.

Comment: The 3rd line confirms what I figured out - it declares a type TBL_ASSMNTCOMP that is a table with rows of type TBL_ASSMNTCOMP_T, which is table with rows of type REC_ASSMNTCOMP - a "table of tables", or effectively a matrix. So if variable X is of that type, you can access a single element like X(i)(j).